# How does Facebook pick background color when sharing URL?

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sharer

I see from few days that facebook allows a dynamic background color for facebook pages's posts/shares.
Example:

[image]

I'm asking if it's possible to pick this color with a meta tag or may be open graph API.
I founded many posts like this, and it seems facebook take the average/dominant color of the post thumbnail, like in this examples:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6LUJ.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzUJn.png

But sometime, it's not the dominant color:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wA37G.png

Somebody know something about how to pick and manage the colors for the facebook posts?
Many thanks

Edit 1: It seems that actually, this background is only on the facebook website on mobile. Not in the app, and not on desktop.

Comment: I guess these are probably Instant Articles ... (?)

Comment: You think we can't get this background when we just share the link?